# Is there a workaround to checkbox control value property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am aware of the fact that there is no value property for checkbox control but is there a workaround to this issue?

We would like to have a bunch of urls with url passed as a value to a checkbox.

The url will be generated from the db. Then using jQuery, create the ability to check all/uncheckall. This way, users can check a checkbox with url or several checkboxes and the value of url will be generatedd. I can handle this part.

This is done in classic asp as thus:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="url" value="<%=url%>" /> http://google.com
```

However, I am not sure how this is accomplished in asp.net

I actually found something like this custom control that I suppose is used to override CheckBox control.

As I understand it, this control is used to add a Value property and it is supposed to be available serverside as well as client side.

My issue is that I am not sure how to apply this to my situation.

```
public class ValueCheckBox : CheckBox 
{ 
    public string Value 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    } 

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) 
    { 
        writer.AddAttribute("value", this.Value); 
        base.Render(writer); 
    } 
}
```

If there is an alternative, perhaps easier solution than this, I would greatly appreciate this as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is only for HTML5 browsers, then you can use the data attribute

```
<input id=checkbox1 type=checkbox data-url="http://wwww.a.com" />
```

In jquery, you can retrieve it using:

```
var myData = $('#checkbox1').data('url');
```

One solution (which is not very clean), if you want to support older browsers as well could be have hidden fields rendered alongside your checkboxes.

```
<input id=checkbox1 type=checkbox  />
<input id=checkbox1Value type=hidden value="http://wwww.a.com" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishal. I am not sure I understand the second part of your proposed solution. How can the 2 be used? In other words, one checkbox has id of checkbox1 and the hidden has id of checkbox1Value. Also, can these still work with asp.net app because I don't see runat="server"?

Comment: This is what the eventual output can be in html. Whatever server side technology we use, at the end of the day it will end up spitting out some html that the browser will render. In case of asp.net, you can create a server side control (either a custom control or a user control) that has two child elements: a checkbox and a hidden field.

Comment: Thank you @Vishal. I got that but I still would like to understand the concept behind the hidden attribute. How are the 2 checkbox IDs linked? One has id of checkbox1 and the other has id of checkbox1Value. How are 2 tied together? I am just trying to understand it. I have been googling it and will continue. Thanks for all your help. The 2 IDs are not the same. That's what is confusing me. Right now, I am so desparate to get a solution for this that I don't care about the cleanliness; I just want it to work.

Comment: It's a lot more simple solution than what you are thinking. Since a html checkbox tag does not have a value tag, I was recommending you save values in a totally different hidden field, but come up with some sort of convention, so that you know for checkbox1, the associated hidden field could be checkbox1HiddenValue or anything you choose it to be. We are doing this because two html form tags cannot have the same id. So in the client code, if you have an id of a checkbox, you can get the url by something like this:var myData = $('#checkbox1' + theSuffixIChooseForHiddenFieldValue).va();